# Use of concern in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to to use concerns in my project. I would like to build a method to get the date in french for every model I have. Here is my code. Currently, I get the error : wrong argument type Class (expected Module) at the line include DateTime in the model.

Here is my file models/concerns/date_time.rb

```html
module DateTime
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end


  # methods defined here are going to extend the class, not the instance of it
  module ClassMethods
    def date_string
      h = {1=>'Janvier',2=>'Février',3=>'Mars',4=>'Avril',5=>'Mai',6=>'Juin',7=>'Juillet',8=>'Août',9=>'Septembre',10=>'Octobre',11=>'Novembre',12=>'Décembre'}
      "#{self.created_at.day}-#{h[self.created_at.month]}-#{self.created_at.year}"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my file models/demands.rb

```html
class Demand < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DateTime
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions
  validates :project, presence: true
  validates :skill, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Rails built in I18n functionality](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) instead. Doing localization in the model layer is just wrong. Models should only be concerned with data and business logic - not how data (like dates) are presented.

Comment: Additionally, your above method would be a instance instead of a class method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Both of your answers helped me understand my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate issue here is that, because `DateTime` is a [class in the Ruby standard library](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjNlezU9fnGAhWCKj4KHaETA2c&url=http%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fstdlib-1.9.3%2Flibdoc%2Fdate%2Frdoc%2FDateTime.html&ei=E2m1VY3AM4LV-AGhp4y4Bg&usg=AFQjCNEWHuFyEeD4Q4_q0V0VFrJbDY4h0Q&sig2=vOwrkN8GbLev8JmxUA_IZQ&bvm=bv.98717601,d.cWw), Ruby is trying to include that class, not your module. If you rename the module to something unique, say, `UsesDateTime`, your error should go away.

That said, for this particular method, I agree with [max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31640056/5154683).